# ActivityCompat class does not have requestPermission method.

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently updated my Android Studio to 2.3.2 and ever since updating, I am not able to run the project onto my phone. At first, it would show no error during the gradle build. But when you run it on the phone, it gives the following error.

```
Error:(203, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorEditProfileActivity,String[],int)
Error:(213, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorEditProfileActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\DoctorHomeActivity.java
Error:(133, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorHomeActivity,String[],int)
Error:(139, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorHomeActivity,String[],int)
Error:(670, 35) error: cannot find symbol method getActionView(MenuItem)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\DoctorReferDoctorActivity.java
Error:(89, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorReferDoctorActivity,String[],int)
Error:(272, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorReferDoctorActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\DoctorSetupProfileActivity.java
Error:(238, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorSetupProfileActivity,String[],int)
Error:(248, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(DoctorSetupProfileActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\GetPermissionActivity.java
Error:(37, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(GetPermissionActivity,String[],int)
Error:(48, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(GetPermissionActivity,String[],int)
Error:(59, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(GetPermissionActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\MyGcmListenerService.java
Error:(54, 59) error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
Error:(606, 49) error: cannot find symbol class BigTextStyle
Error:(613, 65) error: cannot find symbol method build()
Error:(628, 49) error: cannot find symbol class BigTextStyle
Error:(635, 65) error: cannot find symbol method build()
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\PatientEditProfileActivity.java
Error:(245, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientEditProfileActivity,String[],int)
Error:(256, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientEditProfileActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\PatientSendReportActivity.java
Error:(97, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientSendReportActivity,String[],int)
Error:(107, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientSendReportActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\PatientSetupProfileActivity.java
Error:(403, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientSetupProfileActivity,String[],int)
Error:(414, 43) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(PatientSetupProfileActivity,String[],int)
C:\Users\Narendran\Desktop\Appsilon\Floater\CloudTest\app\src\main\java\com\dovo\health\appsilonapp\SplashScreenActivity.java
Error:(207, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(SplashScreenActivity,String[],int)
Error:(220, 27) error: cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(SplashScreenActivity,String[],int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 14.028 secs
Information:26 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

requestPermission which is a method in ActivityCompat cannot be found. I tried clicking on ActivityCompat to check the source and it doesn't have requestPermission method in it. In fact, there are only 2 methods in ActivityCompat.

I am sharing my app gradle here with all the dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.dovo.health.xxxxx'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 39
        versionName '1.2.3'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':DoctorBackend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    //Sinch
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.citruspay.sdk:payment-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.4'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev107-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.wu-man:android-oauth-client:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.38'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the usage of requestPermission that is giving the error. This is called in an Activity not a fragment.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                        } else {
                            chooseGalleryImage();
                        }
```

Comment: May be an issue with "Instant run". Try disabling it from the preference and see the result. Or perform clean build.

Comment: @Milanix I tried disabling instant run, cleaning the project and then running it. it is still giving the same error. I am at a complete loss. Most intriguing thing is when I open ActivityCompat, it only shows these two methods in it - invalidateOptionsMenu and startActivities.

Comment: does `ActivityCompat` come from  `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat` available via gradle `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'`

Comment: @k3b hey i am unsure. package for ActivityCompat shows android.support.v4.app.  how can I tell which Package it is being taken from? I removed the support-v4 dependency and it doesn't show an error on ActivityCompat.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue. I've changed the order of the lines with "compile" in dependencies.

----

Work:
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
 compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'

-----

Doesn't Work:
 compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
 compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

------

So probably some dependencies.